# JET SQL for Access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003, jet-sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
Select Choose(1,Orders.Employee, Orders.Customer) as Name1, 
Choose(2,Orders.Employee, Orders.Customer) as Name2, [Shipped Date]
FROM Orders;
```

However, the field "[Shipped Date]" has a space in it and hence why I have put square brackets around it. The problem is, in SQL view, it seems to think that the sqaure brackets means its a parameter and its asks me for a value but I don't want a value, I want to be able to select that field name!

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Your question is very confusing, as your SQL is equivalent to:
"SELECT Orders.Employee AS Name1, Orders.Customer AS Name2, [Shipped Date] FROM Orders;". Also, it seems rather inconsistent of you to fully qualify the Employee and Customer fields with the table name and then fail to do so for [Shipped Date]. It really oughtn't make a difference, seems to me, but consistency would have saved you the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 Orders.[Shipped Date]
```

As an aside, it seems a little odd to use Choose when the descision is already made.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have worked for me! I am just testing out if I remember Jet SQL as I use to and this SQL statement is not for a live server! :)